# Sending a newsletter more than once?

Tags: emails

Is it possible to re-send a newsletter once it's been sent?

I am using a [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module and the [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module).

Answer (score 1):

go to phpmyadmin database ->

go to table -> ' simplenews_newsletter '

Sent newsletter will have status 2, pending will have 1 and not sent will be 0.

edit and change the status of that newsletter to 0

Hurrey!!!! send it again :)